# Improving poor man's translations mechanism in c++98 program

Tags: c++, strings, static, c++98

In order to add basic translation capabilities in an old c++98 program
I've come up to a basic and shameless code summarized by this
[snippet](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GPT15751z):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Translation ids
enum
   {
    TR_RELOAD =0,
    TR_SAVE,
    TR_MSGWARNRESET,
    TR_MSGAPPLYCHANGES
   };


// (Returning an array reference)
const std::string (&resolve_translation(const std::string& lang))[]
{
    static const std::string tr_en[] =
       {
        "Reload",      // TR_RELOAD
        "Save",       // TR_SAVE
        "Current values will be lost, are you sure?", // TR_MSGWARNRESET
        "Apply changes to material %s?" // TR_MSGAPPLYCHANGES
       };

    static const std::string tr_it[] =
       {
        "Ricarica", // TR_RELOAD
        "Salva",    // TR_SAVE
        "I valori correnti saranno persi, sei sicuro?", // TR_MSGWARNRESET
        "Applicare modifiche al materiale %s?" // TR_MSGAPPLYCHANGES
       };

    static const std::string tr_es[] =
       {
        "Recargar", // TR_RELOAD
        "Salvar",   // TR_SAVE
        "Los valores actuales se perderán, está seguro?", // TR_MSGWARNRESET
        "¿Aplicar cambios al material %s?" // TR_MSGAPPLYCHANGES
       };

    static const std::string tr_fr[] =
       {
        "Recharger",   // TR_RELOAD
        "Enregistrer", // TR_SAVE
        "Les valeurs actuelles seront perdues, êtes-vous sûr?", // TR_MSGWARNRESET
        "Appliquer les modifications au matériau %s?" // TR_MSGAPPLYCHANGES
       };

    if(lang=="en") return tr_en;
    if(lang=="it") return tr_it;
    if(lang=="fr") return tr_fr;
    if(lang=="es") return tr_es;
    return tr_en; // default
}


int main()
{
    std::string lang = "it"; // unknown at compile time
    const std::string (&tr)[] = resolve_translation(lang);
    std::cout << tr[TR_RELOAD] << '\n';
    std::cout << tr[TR_MSGWARNRESET] << '\n';
}
```

The usage is cumbersone because needs a local call to `resolve_translation`,
however I can compile it in bcc and g++ and is working,
but I'm not sure why does not compile with clang and msvc,
I fear that there's some major problem under the rug.

I'm seeking some advices to improve it.

Comment: I'm sure Clang and MSVC give some kind of error message and location, right?  You might include that detail so someone might be able to tell you want it means.

Comment: @JDługosz Yes! I didn't want to stuff too many things, but opted to include the compiler explorer link exactly for that reason

Comment: I didn't follow the link; assumed it was a Stack Exchange _snippet_ that was equivalent to the listing with maybe some boilerplate that's not shown below.

Comment: GCC shows the same error when invoked in a standards-conformant mode: `g++ -std=c++98 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra` - "_warning: conversions to arrays of unknown bound are only available with `-std=c++2a` or `-std=gnu++2a`_".

Comment: You must not edit the code in a Code Review after it has been posted and answered.  If you have a new revision, you can post it in another Question, and refer back to this one, and you can edit this one to note that there is a newer one too.

Comment: @JDługosz Even though the changes are just aesthetic and don't affect the replies?

Comment: @MatG yes, I've gotten rolled back for adding whitespace and fixing typos in comments!  In general, we can't tell that the changes are cosmetic, and even if they are that might have been mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improvements:

The return type is strange and awkward enough that it needs a comment to explain it!  What benefit does returning a reference to an array have over simply returning a pointer to the first element?

It would be *better* to return an object.  It might simply contain a pointer and length, but it means you could update it to support dynamically loaded tables or other new features, and do error checking on the `operator[]`, and use a strong type for the subscript as well (that is, it requires the enumeration constant, not just any old integer).

Building an array of `std::string` is inefficient since it copies all of the literals into the `string` object at run time.  If you're compiling as C++98 you don't have `string_view` built in, but you could supply your own as part of the program, or make it an array of plain `char*` instead.  I guess it depends on how the return values are being used: if it repeatedly needs to convert that to a `string` you'd rather have it done and remembered.  But you don't need to copy and consume memory for all the unused tables.  That's another reason to make it an abstract object, as it can be optimized and improved "under the hood" later without changing the usage.

## the compiler error

> reference to incomplete type 'const std::string []' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'const std::string [4]'

The function's type is declared without bounds.  It's not like an initializer where the actual array in the `return` statement will inform it; though apparently g++ accepts that as an extension (sort of an implicit partial `auto`).  From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Arrays_of_unknown_bound): (emphasis mine)

> If expr is omitted in the declaration of an array, the type declared is "array of unknown bound of T", which is a kind of incomplete type, **except when used in a declaration with an aggregate initializer**.
> ⋮
> References and pointers to arrays of unknown bound can be formed, **but cannot be initialized or assigned from arrays and pointers to arrays of known bound**.

Your code is actually illegal in standard C++.

Comment: All your points make sense, I'll consider each one to straighten up this mess.

Comment: The return type "needs a comment" - or perhaps a name?  Giving it a name leads naturally towards the next paragraph, a user-defined object type.

Comment: @TobySpeight In other words, a `typedef` would improve the readability, that's a valuable observation. Specifying also the array size would make the code more conformant. I'll try to smooth the rough edges keeping the runtime overhead as minimum ad possible.

Comment: @MatG, does C++98 not have `using`?  If not, then `typedef` would have to do.