# Improving poor man's translations mechanism in c++98 program (follow-up)

Tags: c++, strings, static, c++98

As a follow-up to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/266416/241620)
that was an [attempt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s35885qos)
to add basic translation capabilities in an old c++98 program
for the sake of the community, I'm posting here the first iteration
of my [code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dW6qG8ecE)
after applying some of the points that emerged from the previous question:

````
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Not nested in class definition to avoid class namespace in code
enum
   {
    TR_RELOAD=0,
    TR_SAVE,
    TR_SIZ
   };

class PoorMansTranslations
{
 private:
    std::string i_tr[TR_SIZ]; // Actual translation strings

    // Here to be near the enum, consistency is by hand!
    typedef char tr_chars_t[TR_SIZ][16]; // Translation string tables with static linkage
    static const tr_chars_t& resolve_lang(const std::string& lang) throw()
       {
        static const tr_chars_t tr_en =
           {
            "Reload", // TR_RELOAD
            "Save"    // TR_SAVE
           };

        static const tr_chars_t tr_it =
           {
            "Ricarica", // TR_RELOAD
            "Salva"     // TR_SAVE
           };

        static const tr_chars_t tr_es =
           {
            "Recargar", // TR_RELOAD
            "Salvar",   // TR_SAVE
           };

        static const tr_chars_t tr_fr =
           {
            "Recharger",  // TR_RELOAD
            "Enregistrer" // TR_SAVE
           };

             if(lang=="en") return tr_en;
        else if(lang=="it") return tr_it;
        else if(lang=="fr") return tr_fr;
        else if(lang=="es") return tr_es;
        return tr_en; // Fallback lang
       }

 public:
    const std::string& operator[](const std::size_t idx) const throw() { return i_tr[idx]; }

    void select_lang(const std::string& lang) throw()
       {
        const tr_chars_t& tr_arr = resolve_lang(lang);
        // Constructing the strings on demand
        for(int i=0; i<TR_SIZ; ++i) i_tr[i] = std::string(tr_arr[i]);
       }
} tr;


int main()
{
    std::string lang = "it"; // note: unknown at compile time

    tr.select_lang(lang);
    std::cout << tr[TR_RELOAD] << ", " << tr[TR_SAVE] << '\n';

    lang = "bad";
    tr.select_lang(lang);
    std::cout << tr[TR_RELOAD] << ", " << tr[TR_SAVE] << '\n';
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid hardcoding translation strings to 16 bytes

There's no need to set the size of the strings to 16 bytes, just store them as pointers to `const char` instead of arrays of `char`:

```
typedef const char *tr_chars_t[TR_SIZ];
```

## Store all languages in an array

For each language you have a separate variable holding the translations strings, and you have a long if-then-chain to find the right variable given the languages name. You can make the code more generic by storing all languages in an array, like so:

```
static const tr_chars_t &resolve_lang(const std::string &lang) throw()
{
    static const struct {
        const char *lang;
        const tr_chars_t translations;
    } languages[] = {
        {
            "en", {
                "Reload", // TR_RELOAD
                "Save"    // TR_SAVE
            }
        },
        {
            "it", {
                "Ricarica", // TR_RELOAD
                "Salva"     // TR_SAVE
            }
        },
        ...
    };

    static const std::size_t n_languages = sizeof languages / sizeof * languages;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n_languages; ++i) {
        if (lang == languages[i].lang) {
            return languages[i].translations;
        }
    }

    return languages[0].translations; // Fallback lang
}
```

This way, when adding a language, you only have to add an entry to the array `languages[]`, and not change any other code.

You could even improve it a bit by ensuring the languages are ordered alphabetically, so you can do a binary search.

## Consider using STL algorithms

Copying the C strings in to the array of `std::string`s can be done with [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
void select_lang(const std::string &lang) throw()
{
    const tr_chars_t &tr_arr = resolve_lang(lang);
    std::copy(tr_arr, tr_arr + TR_SIZ, i_tr);
}
```

You could also use `std::find()` or `std::lower_bound()` to replace the for-loop in my version of `resolve_lang()`, but it's a bit awkward in C++98 since you can't use a lambda for the comparator.

## Consider storing the translation strings in `std::string`s

Instead of storing the translation strings in arrays of regular C strings, you can also consider storing them in arrays of `std::string`s. The drawback is that they will all be initialized once at runtime, but then you can just return a reference to that array, instead of copying the C strings into `i_tr`. Which method is best depends on how many languages you want to support versus how often you switch languages in your code multiplied by the number of strings in a language.

Comment: A compromise is to make an array of `string_view` which avoids copying the bytes but give the performance of knowing the actual length without scanning for the terminator.  As I noted in my earlier answer, with C++98 you can include such a class as part of your project even if it's not in your copy of the standard library that's old enough to drink.

Comment: I'll definitely apply the first points (not sure where post the code update), regarding storing all in `std::string` I think the advantage depends on how frequent is the switching between langs, in my use case it occurs once at start.

Comment: Here's the [next version](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xWsrhWebz)

Comment: If you want the next version reviewed, you're welcome to post it as a new question on CodeReview!